# Create Json dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I need to create a Json object dynamically by looping through columns.
so declaring an empty json object then add elements to it dynamically.

eg:

```
List<String> columns = new List<String>{"FirstName","LastName"};

var jsonObj = new {};

for(Int32 i=0;i<columns.Count();i++)
    jsonObj[col[i]]="Json" + i;
```

And the final json object should be like this:

```
jsonObj={FirstName="Json0", LastName="Json1"};
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
[TestFixture]
public class DynamicJson
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        dynamic flexible = new ExpandoObject();
        flexible.Int = 3;
        flexible.String = "hi";

        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)flexible;
        dictionary.Add("Bool", false);

        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary); // {"Int":3,"String":"hi","Bool":false}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yape that is what I am looking for, thanks.I will try it and get back with you

Comment: Is it possible to get something like: { "Schools": [ {"name": "test"}, {"name": "testing"} ] } with the ExpandoObject approach? the array name, Schools in this example, should be a variable.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann consider asking a new question with more detail. i'm not sure what you're after based upon your comment.

Answer (score 22):

You should use the `JavaScriptSerializer`. That can Serialize actual types for you into JSON :)

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

**EDIT: Something like this?**

```
var columns = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "FirstName", "Mathew"},
                { "Surname", "Thompson"},
                { "Gender", "Male"},
                { "SerializeMe", "GoOnThen"}
            };

var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var serialized = jsSerializer.Serialize(columns);
```

Output:

```
{"FirstName":"Mathew","Surname":"Thompson","Gender":"Male","SerializeMe":"GoOnThen"}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of json.net, you got a link? I've used JavaScriptSerializer for both serialization and deserialization in the past and it's always served me well :)

Comment: Oded because it's available in the .Net framework. No 3rd party DLL required.

Comment: @SpencerRuport - Not everything that comes with the BCL is the best of breed.

Comment: @Oded I suspect it was a case of mistaken tagging :). What exactly does json.net offer that the JavaScriptSerializer doesn't? I have no problems with using 3rd party tools, as long as the benefit is there. For someone not even sure how to build a JSON string, I think built in .NET behaviour should be more than adequate :)

Comment: I didn't ask to serialize or deserialize please read my case well, I want to create a dynamic Json so I can add elements to it dynamically, if you guys have an example please post it asap.

Comment: @AlaaOsta you are actually asking how to serialize items to JSON, albeit adding elements dynamically or any other way :). I'll post an example, give me 10 minutes :)

Comment: Just so I know, what types are your columns?

Comment: @mattytommo OK, I am waiting thanks for ur help. Type of columns is string, just give me the key of building non constant json object and I will complete the rest

Comment: @mattytommo can you check my example again please

Comment: @AlaaOsta are you expecting an actual object that corresponds to the JSON, or a JSON string? Is there any reason you're both setting the value to the columns and adding them to the JSON at the same time?

Comment: I can see you are using var to create final serialized variable. Can we put this in a function and what would be the return type. I have a helper library and would like to add this to that so i can pass list of columns and list of items and it iterates and generate dynamic json but it should return json so i can use it in many controllers.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani Yeah it can be put into a function, the datatype of the serialized variable is string, check here for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize.aspx

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution very similar to DPeden, though there is no need to use the IDictionary, you can pass directly from an `ExpandoObject` to a JSON convert:

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = "something";
foo.Test = true;
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

and the output becomes:

```
{ "FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Doe", "Active":true }
```

Comment: This is is best and easy solution

Comment: This isn't exactly what they asked for. Their property names exist in strings in a list. You just hardcoded Bar and Test.

Comment: @n4rzul I don't understand the reason for your downvote when you most probably haven't even tried it. It's only hardcoded for demo purposes, you can replace the hardcode value by any dynamic values.

Comment: Actually, @ghiscoding, I think @n4rzul is right. You cannot add fields from a string in this way: `dictionary.Add(myFieldName, false);` with your solution.

Comment: @ghiscoding Please read the exact question carefully. There is a very specific problem they are trying to solve and simply hardcoding Bar and Test does NOT solve their *specific* problem.

Comment: The dictionary is not needed AFAICT. I also go to the convert directly from the expando...

Answer (score 11):

Using `dynamic` and `JObject`:

```
dynamic obj = new JObject();
obj.ProductName = "Elbow Grease";
obj.Enabled = true;
obj.StockCount = 9000;
```

Another way to assign properties:

```
var obj = new JObject();
obj["ProductName"] = "Elbow Grease";
obj["Enabled"] = true;
obj["StockCount"] = 9000;
```

Or using `JObject.FromObject`:

```
JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    ProductName = "Elbow Grease",
    Enabled = true,
    StockCount = 9000
});
```

They all produce this result:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
// {
//   "ProductName": "Elbow Grease",
//   "Enabled": true,
//   "StockCount": 9000
// }
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: That is not what they asked for. Their attribute names exist as strings in a list. Your attributes are hard coded.

Comment: @n4rzul with JObject you can do: `obj["FirstName"] = "The Persons Name";`