# Convert C# Typed List to JSON Array with specified property

Tags: c#, json

I want to convert a list of strings to a JSON array for a request.

Code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(isins);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(_BaseUri, content);

            return response;
        }
```

I was suggested to use .NET's built in library to serialize my list and the result looks similar to below.

Current Output:

```
{
  ["GG00B933LL68","US88688T1007"]
}
```

However as I'm passing this to an API it requires a property name, in my case 'ISIN'.
I need to create the below, is there a quick way to supply a property name without building a model?

Desired Output:

```
{
  "ISIN": ["GG00B933LL68","US88688T1007"]
}
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Make an instance of a class with one `List<string>` field names `ISIN`, set the `isins` variable you have now to that field, and then serialize the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Json dynamically in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252675/create-json-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just build a Dictionary: `var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "ISIN", new List<string>() { "GG00B933LL68", "US88688T1007" } } };` and serialize that.

Comment: or `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { "ISIN" : isins });`

Answer (score 0):

> the result looks similar to below

Similar indeed - I can't think of a way to throw something into a serializer and get a single array wrapped in `{` `}` out - if `isins` is an enumerable of string the `{}` wouldn't be seen in the output and if `isins` is something more complex, the array should be prefixed with a property name..

Anyhow, there aren't many rocket appliances here..

> quick way to supply a property name without building a model

Sure, get the compiler to make you an anonymous type:

```
var isins = new[] { "GG00B933LL68","US88688T1007" };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new{ ISINS = isins});
```