# Declare an implicit variable in C# Directory

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have met a issues that I couldn't declare `var` into `Dictionary` in c#.
Is there any way to declare a implicity datatype in `Dictionary` in c#?

**The current declaration of my codes**

`IDictionary<string, var> serializeMetadata = new Dictionary<string, var>();`

With the shown code, my Visual Studio IDE returns an error of

> The contextual keyword "var" may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code

Comment: you'd better provide more context, i.e. why you want such dict.

Comment: The error message suggests this is a field and not a local variable?  You can't use type inference when defining class members and, otherwise, you can't use `var` for a type parameter.  Are you immediately populating `serializeMetadata` with entries of the desired type?  If so, you could potentially define the variable as `var serializeMetadata = ...` and then use, say, `.ToDictionary()` to build a dictionary out of some input without specifying the type.  At some point that input type would need to either be known or a type parameter itself, though.  You'll need to show more code in that case

Comment: @LeiYang the purpose of using such dict is to cope with my ever changing Json file. I would like to read and copy out certain objects that are matched for my requirement and then paste to a new json file that i created for another purposes.

Comment: can you put those context in the question, instead of comment. also [ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253036/1518100) may be help.

Comment: If it's only json-processing without using the objects in your C#, try simply deserialize it, put whatever you want into `List<object>` or `Dictionary<string, object>`, then serialize it again. I use `Newtonsoft.Json` and it can serialize `List<object>` with `object`s read as each one's derived class. However I deserialize my json into a defined type though... You might have to test around. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411008/16606026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object`. Below is the basic example:-

```
Dictionary<string, object> storage = new Dictionary<string,object>();

storage.Add("age", 12);
storage.Add("name", "test");
storage.Add("bmi", 24.1);

int a = (int)storage["age"];
string b = (string)storage["name"];
double c = (double)storage["bmi"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object`:

```
var serializeMetadata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Comment: but what if one of the key value pair is containing an array? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That's not the same, though.  Among other reasons, what if `var` would be a value type?  Or if the `var` type always is and must be guaranteed (by the compiler) to be the same type?